# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n\sin(\pi/n))^n$ with L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

Heres how I think it should be done, but I seem to be getting the wrong answer.

$$\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{n^{-1}}$$

becomes this by differentiating.

$$\frac{\cos(\pi/n)\pi}{-n^{-2}} = \frac{\pi}{-1/n^2}$$

the limit of this should equal pi/ but the way i worked it out I get $\frac{n^2\pi}{-1}$. This throws off my whole answer, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: the ^n makes it nasty why do you ignore it ?

Comment: @Billy You didn't differentiate the numerator correctly. Don't forget the chain rule. Also please be aware that you need a real function of real variable to use L'Hôpital. If you're gonna use the letter $n$, please make it clear that you're considering $n$ over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: ahh you guys are right, silly mistake

Answer (score 4):

At first we change the following: $x=\frac{1}{n}$, so the limit as $n\to \infty$ is the same as $x\to 0$ while $x>0$

Than you get the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
As the part in the parenthesis converges to $\pi$ taking the $n$-th power will diverge surely.

Answer (score 2):

by differentiating,

$$
\frac{\cos(\pi / n) \cdot \frac{-\pi}{n^2}} {\frac{-1}{n^2}}
$$

Comment: I improved the $\LaTeX$ in your question. You can rollback if you wish to by going to the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/346441/revisions) history.

Comment: am i the only one who sees the n-th power in the title ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I never read the title once I open the link to the question. It's the OP's fault, to be honest. But you're right.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you^^ I re-edit it using $$. I am a beginner for this site and appreciated your edit.

Comment: @topy The usual functions like $\log, \cos, \arctan$, etc should be written as \log, \cos, \artan, etc. You're welcome.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, very thanks! and I just saw n-th power in the title. I don't know what is right.

Answer (score 2):

$(n\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{n}))^n=(\dfrac{\sin{\pi x}}{x})^{\frac 1 x}$ if  $x= \frac 1 n$ and if $n\to \infty$ ,$x\to 0^+$

$(\dfrac{\sin{\pi x}}{x})\to\pi$ . So the $\frac{1}{x}$th power(with $x\to 0^+$) of this will diverge to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about having the same answer, I didn't notice it till after typing.